# Error when trying to install Django CMS in virtualenv w/ MySQL on Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, django, macos

I am getting the following error when I try to install django CMS with MySQL using virutalenv:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

/Users/ethan/Sites/env/build/mysql-python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/Users/ethan/Sites/env/build/mysql-python/setup.py", line 7, in <module>

    use_setuptools()

  File "distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools

    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)

  File "distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download

    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)

  File "distribute_setup.py", line 116, in _build_egg

    raise IOError('Could not build the egg.')

IOError: Could not build the egg.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/ethan/Sites/env/build/mysql-python
```

The command I am using for the install is the following:

```
env/bin/pip install --download-cache=~/.pip-cache -r reqs.txt
```

And the reqs.txt file looks like this:

```
django-cms==2.4.1  
Django==1.5.1  
django-classy-tags==0.4  
South==0.8.1  
html5lib==1.0b1  
django-mptt==0.5.2  
django-sekizai==0.7  
six==1.3.0  
Pillow==2.0.0  
django-filer==0.9.4  
cmsplugin-filer==0.9.5  
django-reversion==1.7  
mysql-python==1.2.4
```

I'm a novice to django (just going through the tutorial) and I cannot find anything in a search that seems to resolve this issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is you virtualenv active when you are trying to run "pip install -r reqs.txt" ?

Comment: Do you mean by activate, whether I have run the `source env/bin/activate` command? If so, yes.

Comment: I tried it with the virtualenv active, i.e. after running the above command, and then again after running `source ~/.bash_profile`. Same errors. Could this have something to do with it not finding my mysql installation?

Comment: Most Django devs use Postgres SQL.  I'd recommend using Postgres because I've never run into this issue.  I'm not sure about MySQL if it conflicts with VirtualEnv or not.

Comment: @AronYsidoro, well I took your advice and that worked. Guess the mysql link is just problematic?

Comment: cool. Yea I've been happy with Postgres. So far so good!  Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your requirement to mysql-python==1.2.5, I had the same problem on a CentOS 6.3 server.

Answer (score 9):

mysql-python v. 1.2.4 has a hard dependency on distribute version 0.6.28. It might not be picking the right version of distribute.

Run this after the virtual env is activated:

```
easy_install distribute==0.6.28
```

and you should be good to proceed with

```
env/bin/pip install --download-cache=~/.pip-cache -r reqs.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

change requirement to mysql-python==1.2.5 also worked for me on OS X mavericks with pip install